# Java 8 Collector chaining for nested 1 To Many relation

Tags: java-8

I am using java 8 stream and collector for iterating over a collection. At the end of the operation I have to transform the objects contained in the stream to relevant business objects. And these business objects has relation 1 to Many. 
For clear description below are the classes used.

The first is Helper class which represents the collection i will have on my stream.

```
public class Helper{
    private String a;
    private String additionalA;
    private String additionalB;
    private String additionalC;
    //constructor, setter, getter, equals, hashCode omitted.
}
```

Bean A is the unitary bean no relation, just primitives.

```
public class BeanA{
        private String a;
        private String additionalA;
        //constructor, setter, getter, equals, hashCode omitted.
}
```

Bean B has 1 to Many relation to Bean A as well as additional infos

```
public class BeanB{
        private List<BeanA> beanA = new ArrayList<BeanA>();
        private String additonalB;
       //constructor, setter, getter, equals, hashCode omitted.
}
```

BeanC has 1 to Many relation to BeanB as well as additional infos

```
public static class BeanC {
        private List<BeanB> beanB = new ArrayList<BeanB>();
        private String additionalC;
        //constructor, setter, getter, equals, hashCode omitted.
}
```

In addition I also have several methods for conversion such as:

```
public static BeanA getBeanA(Helper helper) {
    BeanA a = new BeanA();
    a.setA(helper.getA());
    a.setAdditionalA(helper.getAdditionalA());
    return a;
}

public static BeanB getBeanB(Helper helper) {
    BeanB b = new BeanB();
    //maybe wrong to add the data to list (see below)
    b.getBeanA().add(getBeanA(helper));
    b.setAdditonalB(helper.getAdditionalB());
    return b;
}

public static BeanC getBeanC(Helper helper) {
    BeanC c = new BeanC();
    //maybe wrong to add the data to list (see below)
    c.getBeanB().add(getBeanB(helper));
    c.setAdditionalC(helper.getAdditionalC());
    return c;

}
```

and the expected result is a map

```
Map<BeanC,Map<BeanB,List<BeanA>>>
```

and i have
the following block for producing the desired result:

```
Map<BeanC, Map<BeanB, List<BeanA>>> res = helpers.stream()
                .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(
                        Test::getBeanC,
                        Collectors.groupingBy(Test::getBeanB, 
                                Collectors.collectingAndThen(Collectors.toList(), 
                                        list -> list.stream()
                                                    .map(Test::getBeanA)
                                                    .collect(Collectors.toList())))));
```

Problem is that the list on BeanC and BeanB is not set correctly.

Anyone know how to achieve initialize the 1 to Many relation using collector?

Comment: What do you mean with “*that the list on BeanC and BeanB is not set correctly*”? Be more specific with your problem description. Besides that, the `Collectors.collectingAndThen(Collectors.toList(), list-> list.stream() .map(Test::getBeanA) .collect(Collectors.toList()))` collector is a very convoluted variant of `Collectors.mapping(Test::getBeanA, Collectors.toList())`…

Comment: @Holger I have to populate the list on BeanC and BeanB. I was trying to find out how to do that using collector by chaining it will collectors mapping and some manipulation on factory methods.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can’t use the grouping function to populate a collection. The grouping function is evaluated for each stream element (i.e. `Helper` instance) to build the groups based on the *equality* of the results. Your `getBeanC` and `getBeanB` methods create a *new bean each time*, populated with one nested object, all but one of these objects being dropped for each group, after equality has been checked.

Your question doesn’t show, how the equality of these beans is defined, but considering that `additionalC` and `additionalB` are the only data ever passed to them, I assume that these properties determine the equality. Hence, you should group the `Helper` instances by these properties first, before converting the groups to the bean instance, i.e.

```
Map<String, Map<String, List<Helper>>> tmp = helpers.stream()
    .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Helper::getAdditionalC,
        Collectors.groupingBy(Helper::getAdditionalB)));
```

now, for converting them to the bean instances, it will be helpfull to adapt your factory methods:

```
public static BeanB getBeanB(String bId, List<Helper> beanA) {
    BeanB b = new BeanB();
    b.getBeanA().addAll(beanA.stream().map(Test::getBeanA).collect(Collectors.toList()));
    b.setAdditonalB(bId);
    return b;
}

public static BeanC getBeanC(String cId, Map<String,List<Helper>> beanB) {
    BeanC c = new BeanC();
    c.getBeanB().addAll(beanB.entrySet().stream()
        .map(e -> getBeanB(e.getKey(), e.getValue()))
        .collect(Collectors.toList()));
    c.setAdditionalC(cId);
    return c;
}
```

(`getBeanA`) remains unchanged.

Then, you can build the final `Map` as

```
Map<BeanC, Map<BeanB, List<BeanA>>> res = tmp.entrySet().stream()
    .map(e -> Test.getBeanC(e.getKey(), e.getValue()))
    .collect(Collectors.toMap(Function.identity(),
        c -> c.getBeanB().stream()
              .collect(Collectors.toMap(Function.identity(), BeanB::getBeanA))));
```

though, considering that all beans are reachable through the `BeanC` instances, you most probably don’t want the `Map` and it only was an artifact of the grouping operation. So you can simply collect into a `List<BeanC>` instead:

```
List<BeanC> list = tmp.entrySet().stream()
    .map(e -> Test.getBeanC(e.getKey(), e.getValue()))
    .collect(Collectors.toList());
```